# Extract specific data from string using Regex (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, string

My objective is to check if the message have emojis or not , if yes i am going to convert them. 
I am having a problem to find out how many emojis are in the string.

**Example :**

```
$string = ":+1::+1::+1:"; //can be any string that has :something: between ::
```

- the objective here is to get the :+1: ( all of them ) but i tried two pattern and i keep getting only 1 match.

  ```
  preg_match_all('/:(.*?):/', $string, $emojis, PREG_SET_ORDER); // $emojis is declared as $emojis='' at the beginning.
  preg_match_all('/:(\S+):/', $string, $emojis, PREG_SET_ORDER);
  ```

**The Rest of the code**
after getting the matches i am doing this :

```
 if (isset($emojis[0])) 
   {
        $stringMap = file_get_contents("/api/common/emoji-map.json");
        $jsonMap = json_decode($stringMap, true);

        foreach ($emojis as $key => $value) {
            $emojiColon = $value[0];
            $emoji = key_exists($emojiColon, $jsonMap) ? $jsonMap[$emojiColon] : '';
            $newBody = str_replace($emojiColon, $emoji, $newBody);
        }
   }
```

i would appreciate any help or suggestions , Thanks.

Comment: I get all 3 matches with preg_match_all https://3v4l.org/DLsmq

Comment: i tried that in different cases but i still have some problems , i'll test more tho  , thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated your expression a little bit:

```
preg_match_all('/\:(.+?)(\:)/', $string, $emojis, PREG_SET_ORDER);
echo var_dump($emojis);
```

- The `:` is now escaped, otherwise it could be treated as special character.
- Replaced the `*` by `+`, this way you won't match two consecutive `::` but require at least one charcter in-between.

Comment: Hello bulletvz, welcome to Stackoverflow! Your answer has been flagged because of its short length. For better readable answers next time, please take your time and provide a short comment of what you did to fix the issue.